# Unable to save password for git repository

Tags: git

I have a personal git server on a rPI. On the same rPI, I have read-only clone to automatically run the scripts by a cron task with a `git pull` just before to have the latest version. And it works fine.

Due to the workload increase, I have add a new rPI on the same local network to unload the first one.
So, I have clone a repository with `git clone git@server:repo.git`
But each time I perform a `git pull`, my password is asked, even if I have set `git config --global credential.helper store`. I have tried also to add a `.netrc` but without success !

I probably have missed something, but I don't find what !

Comment: Credential helpers store passwords only for HTTPS protocol. `git@server` is SSH protocol in SCP-like syntax. Either switch to HTTPS protocol or configure SSH keypair. If you already have an SSH keypair and SSH asks for key passphrase — use `ssh-agent`.

Comment: thanks @phd ! I finally understand how ssh keypair works !